# Throw runtime exception in Closable.close()

Tags: java, exception, ocpjp

During my studies to the OCPJP8 I've encountered one question which doesn't have very clear answer to me. Consider following code:

```
public class Animals
{
class Lamb implements Closeable
{
    public void close()
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("a");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new Animals().run();
}

public void run()
{
    try (Lamb l = new Lamb();)
    {
        throw new IOException();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("c");
    }
}
}
```

According to the book correct answer for a question "Which exception will the code throw?" is "Runtime exception c with no suppressed exception".
I have check this code in Eclipse and system.out suggest that the book is right. However, I've also modified the code a bit and added the following system.out just before throwing RuntimeException "c"

```
    System.out.println(e.getSuppressed().toString());
```

and the output I've got from this system.out is:

> [Ljava.lang.Throwable;@75da931b

So clearly there is a suppressed exception. In debug mode, I've also found that this suppressed exception is the one frown in close() method.

Two questions:
1. Why there is no information in the console about exception throwed in close() method?
2. Is the answer given by the book correct?

Comment: As a side note, use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(e.getSuppressed()));` to get a more meaningful output…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The suppressed exception (`RuntimeException`-A) was added to the `IOException` caught in the `catch` and lost from the stack trace printout as it was not passed as the `cause` of the `RuntimeException`-C.

So when the `RuntimeException`-C is printed from the `main` it has no mention of the `IOException` or the suppressed `RuntimeException`-A.

And therefore the book's answer is correct because the only exception that is propagated from the `main` method is `RuntimeException`-C without `cause` (`IOException`), and without any suppressed exceptions (as it was on `IOException`).